# Symfony 3.4, MoneyType, and Bootstrap

Tags: php, symfony, bootstrap-4

I'm having a bit of difficulty styling a `MoneyType` form input the way I want.  I want to use Bootstrap's `input-group-addon` class to prepend a dollar sign to the field, but what's actually happening is that *two* dollar signs are being rendered... one automatically generated by the `MoneyType`, and one that I manually wrote in my template:

Template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.canonicalPrice) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.canonicalPrice) }}
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        {{ form_widget(form.canonicalPrice, { 'attr': {'id': 'price', 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

`MoneyType` definition in my form type class:

```
->add('canonicalPrice', MoneyType::class, array('label' => 'Price', 'currency' => 'USD'))
```

Screenshot:

[image]

So, is there a way for me to either:

1. Hide the automatic currency label that Symfony adds with a `MoneyType` field?  Not specifying any currency defaults to a Euro rather than dollar, which isn't helpful.
2. Style the automatic label the way I want?

Note: I'm not using Symfony's Bootstrap form themes because I like having complete control over my templates.  The fact that `MoneyType` fields default to showing a currency is *very* annoying.

Comment: You should be able to extend the MoneyType and override what you want there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Style the automatic label :**

The dollar sign that is prepend to the input is from the money_pattern attribute of **MoneyType**
So as the [doc on MoneyType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html) says you can :

**Modify in it the view** :

```
{{ form_row(form.value, { 'money_pattern': '{{ widget }} $' }) }}
```

or like this

```
{% block money_widget %}
    {%- set type = type|default('number') -%}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

**Modify it in the builder** :

Use money_pattern in the FormType and set the pattern you want.